# Is it a problem to frequently change a Tor relay's fingerprint

Tags: network-health, private-key

If each time Tor relay is started with a different key pair, would it be a problem for the Tor network to recognize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relay would be considered 'new' each time. It would never gain the 'stable' flag or gain much consensus weight.
This would neither hurt nor help the network.

Comment: What if the same machine switches between only two different public keys? That is, does tor consider the mapping of public keys and IP addresses to tell whether a relay is stable, or public key is the only factor that matters?

Comment: Please add the comment as another question. This helps other to find the question and to answer it in a reasonable way.